# The global vue object is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

First I want reuse my validator on the other component, so I write it on the **myValidator.js**.
I set the vue object to window. Because I needed i18n on my **myValidator.js**. And I got this undefined message. But my other component it's work. I need your help. Thanks.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$t' of undefined
    at Object../src/myValidator.js (VM406 app.js:156668)
    at __webpack_require__ (VM406 app.js:724)
    at fn (VM406 app.js:101)
    at Object../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/HeaderSearch/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (VM406 app.js:4187)
    at __webpack_require__ (VM406 app.js:724)
    at fn (VM406 app.js:101)
    at Module../src/components/HeaderSearch/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (VM406 app.js:157451)
    at __webpack_require__ (VM406 app.js:724)
    at fn (VM406 app.js:101)
    at Module../src/components/HeaderSearch/index.vue (VM406 app.js:157394)
```

**main.js**

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      bus: eventBus
    }
  },
  router,
  store,
  i18n,
  render: h => h(App)
})
window.vm = vm
```

**myValidator.js**

```
export const accountValidatorRule = [{
  required: true,
  message: window.vm.$t('valid.accountBlank'), <-- this $t is undefined
  trigger: 'change'
}, {
  min: 6,
  max: 16,
  message: window.vm.$t('valid.accountRule')
}]
```

**sidebar/Index.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <search ...> <-- this line
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Search from '@/components/HeaderSearch'
...

export default {
  name: 'Index',
  components: { Logo, Search, Menu },
...
</script>
```

**HeaderSearch/Index.vue**

```
<script>
import * as myValidator from '@/myValidator'  <-- this line

export default {
  name: 'Index',
  data() {
    return {
      rules: {
        search: myValidator.accountValidatorRule <-- this line
      },
...
}
```

Comment: I found this solution https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/149#issuecomment-357455921, but I'm still curious about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because `window.vm` is only set to `vm` **after** the App is mounted.

Whereas, the declare of **data()** in **HeaderSearch/Index.vue** is done **before** the App is mounted.

So in order to do this, the most elegant solution is the one you has found in your comment and I really support doing so: https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/149#issuecomment-357455921

However, if you wanna make sure and play around with vue lifecycle, You can try still keep your old code and instead doing this in **HeaderSearch/index.vue**

```
<script>
import * as myValidator from '@/myValidator'  <-- this line

export default {
  name: 'Index',
  data() {
    return {
      rules: {
        search: null <-- assign to nothing first
      },
mounted() {
  // update it after mounted:
    this.rules.search = myValidator.accountValidatorRule <--- the window.vm should be ready now     
}
...
}
```